# How to add a reconnection logic for rabbitmq in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I've created a listener for rabbitmq in nodejs and I want to create a resilient connection which will reconnect in case there's a disconnection.

Here's my current code

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

const rabbitmqServerUrl = 'amqp://localhost';
const queueName = 'best_queue';

let connection = null;
let channel = null;

async function setupConnection() {
  try {
    connection = await amqp.connect(rabbitmqServerUrl);
    connection.on('error', (err) => {
      if (err.message.includes('Connection closed')) {
        console.error('Connection closed, reconnecting...');
        setTimeout(setupConnection, 5000); // Retry connection after a delay
      } else {
        console.error('Connection error:', err.message);
      }
    });

    channel = await connection.createChannel();

    // Create a durable queue
    await channel.assertQueue(queueName, { durable: true });

    console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ');

    // Start the consumer
    startConsumer();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to RabbitMQ:', error.message);

    // Retry connection after a delay
    setTimeout(setupConnection, 5000);
  }
}

function startConsumer() {
  if (!channel) {
    console.error('Channel is not available, skipping consumer start.');
    return;
  }

  channel.consume(queueName, async (msg) => {
    if (msg !== null) {
      try {
        // Process the message
        console.log('Received message:', msg.content.toString());

        // Simulate a processing delay (replace this with your actual processing logic)
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

        // Acknowledge the message
        channel.ack(msg);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error processing message:', err.message);
        // Handle message processing errors as needed
      }
    }
  });

  channel.on('close', () => {
    console.error('Channel closed, reconnecting...');
    setTimeout(startConsumer, 5000); // Restart the consumer after a delay
  });

  channel.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Channel error:', error.message);
    // Handle channel errors as needed
  });

  console.log('Consumer started');
}

setupConnection();
```

When I force disconnect it in the rabbitmq interface it doesn't reconnect.
I'm not sure if this is not possible on localhost or is something missing in my code.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried running your code against my own local RabbitMQ.
Latest RabbitMQ (3.12.6) and Node LTS (18.18.0).

Seemed to be failing with `IllegalOperationError` when trying to reconnect after closing the Node app's connection via `rabbitmqctl close_connection <{Node Process pid}> ""` or stopping the RabbitMQ process via `rabbitmqctl stop`.

I found that replacing your line `setTimeout(startConsumer, 5000);` with `setTimeout(setupConnection, 5000)` resolved the issue and consistently re-established connection with the RabbitMQ server after disconnection.

I guess in your use case it is important to reestablish the AMQP connection and channel before redefining your consumer logic. Let me know how you go!

Comment: that's amazing, thanks a lot for the help